# Should [untagged] die?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was browsing the tags and noticed several questions tagged with [untagged](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

This tag isn't very useful. Should we kill it and replace it with useful tags?

(just wanted to make sure before I went on a retagging rampage :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untagged is automatically added when the last tag on a question is removed. Typically this happens automatically when the system goes and removes tags that have 1 or fewer questions. Unfortunately this sometimes leaves questions without tags, and thus they are marked with [untagged](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

If you see this tag please add appropriate tags to the question so that it does not persist.

Comment: ah, didn't know that! Let the retagging begin... :)